# html2pdf. pdf download is short and not correct

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, jspdf, html2pdf

im using laravel and html2pdf.js to print a specific div on a pdf. As you can see here is my page preview (using blade laravel).

[image]

It has a huge space gap in the bottom. But when I print it the result is like this

[image]

I think it has a margin bottom so that the other part are cut.

here is my blade file.

```
            <div id="pdf" class="card card-outline">
                <br>
                <div>
                    <h3 style="text-align: center" >
                        <b>見積依頼書</b>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body ">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h5>{{$record->outsourcer_info->corpname}}</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div style="" class="col-md-6">
                            <h5 style="text-align: right">{{$record->createdate1}}</h5>
                            <h5 style="text-align: right">三和電子株式会社</h5>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <u>
                                <h5>{{$record->outsourcer_manager_name}}   様</h5>
                            </u>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h5 style="text-align: right">{{$record->sdc_division}}</h5>
                            <h5 style="text-align: right">{{$record->sdc_department}}</h5>
                            <h5 style="text-align: right">{{$record->sdc_manager_name}}</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-top: 30px" class="col-md-12">
                            <u>
                                <h5 style="margin-left: 20px">見積依頼No．： {{$record->sesnum1}} {{str_pad($record->sesnum2, 3, '0',STR_PAD_LEFT)}}</h5>
                            </u>
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-top: 60px" class="col-md-12">
                                <h5 style="margin-left: 50px">  下記、委託業務の見積りをお願いいたします。                                                                           
                                </h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12" >
                           
                          <h5 style="margin-left:50px; padding-top: 40px">  品名 ：      {{$record->workname}}</h5>
                        </div>         

                        <div class="col-md-12" >
                            <br>
                          <h5 style="margin-left:50px">購入仕様書No. ： {{$record->sesnum1}} {{str_pad($record->sesnum2, 3, '0',STR_PAD_LEFT)}}    &nbsp;      #work_date_1 ~ work_date1~6</h5>
                        </div>      
                      
                        <div  class="col-md-12" >
                            <br>
                          <h5 style="margin-left:50px; text-align: right; padding-top: 200px;"> 以　上 </h5>
                        </div>  
               
                        <div style="padding-top: 200px;"  class="col-md-12" >
                            <br>
                          <img  style="float: right" src="{{asset('/img/sanwa_denshi.png')}}" alt="">
                          <br>
                            &nbsp;<p style="text-align: right; margin-left: 500px;"> <b>12345</b></p>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Maybe the problem is because of the margin and the padding? When i remove the padding its better but the preview is not correct. Pls help. Thanks